# helicopters problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Ten helicopters are assigned to find a missing plane. The probability that plane is in one region is $0.7$ and in another region $0.3$. Each helicopter can search only one region and it will find it with the probability of $0.4$. How should we assign helicopters in these two regions so that probability of finding aeroplane will be max?

What I've tried:

Let's say that we send k of them in first region. First thing I am not sure is this. What is the probability that k helicopters will find it? I can't add 0.4 k times. I also can't multiply 0.4 k times because then the probability that it will be found with k helicopters is less than probability with one helicopter.

Comment: The first step is to convert this to some sort of equation(s). Have you done this? Is this the step you are stuck on?

Comment: Yes, here is how I tried: Let's say that we send k of them in first region. First thing I am not sure is this. What is the probability that k helicopters will find it? I can't add 0.4 k times. I also can't multiply 0.4 k times because then the probability that it will be found with k helicopters is less than probability with one helicopter.

Comment: That's a good start.  Consider that each helicopter has a chance of $0.4$ of finding the missing plane (if the helicopter is in the right region).  More than one might be successful, but what is the chance that all will fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it like this:

If I flip a coin, the probability it lands on heads is $1/2$. If I flip a coin twice, the probability it lands on heads is $1/4$.

Likewise, if the plane is in area 1 then one helicopter has a probability of $0.4$ of finding it. So two helicopters have a probability of $0.4^2$ of both finding it. But that's not what we want. Let's try again. One helicopter has a probability of $0.6$ of not finding it. So two helipcopters have a probability of $0.6^2$ of both not finding it. In general, $n$ helicopters have a probability of $0.6^n$ of all not finding it. Finally, $n$ helicopters have a probability of $1 - 0.6^n$ of not all not finding it (i.e. at least one of them finds it).

It then follows that if you send $n$ helicopters to the first area and $10 - n$ to the second, that the probability of any helicopter finding the plane is

$$  0.7(1 - 0.6^n) + 0.3(1 - 0.6^{10 - n}). $$

Verify this. Note that events of the plane being in area 1 or area 2 are mutually exclusive (so you can add the probabilities).

From here create a table of values and find the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say sending n<=10 helicopters to second region(the region with 0.7 prob) brings us a probability function P(n).
We can define P(n) in two situations. One: the plane is in second region
If the plane is in second region the probability of one or many helicopters finding it is 1-(0.6)^n because none of them finding it is (0.6)^n.
Second: the plane is in firat region
The probability becomes 1-(0.6)^(10-n) because we have 10-n helicopters searching and each of them has prob 0.6 not finding it.
Thus, 
P(n) = (0.7)(1-(0.6)^n)+(0.3)(1-(0.6)^(10-n))
dP/dn = (-7/10)((0.6)^n)ln(0.6)+ (3/10)((0.6)^(10-n))ln(0.6) = 0
And
7(0.6)^(2n) = 3(0.6)^10
n = ln(3/7)/2ln(0.6) +5
n ≈ 6.64

Comment: Please use MathJax for mathematical equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference